# How to pass and store item instances?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I am building a Clicker Game with RPG mechanics with Unity. I need some assistance about the logic behind an inventory - or more precisely - an item system. My problem is, It needs to have the following features:

- I want a way to easily manage and modify items and their values, even if they are customized (e.g. when an Item does 20 base dmg and it was modified by the player to do +10 dmg, when I change the base dmg to 30, the players item should do 40 dmg in total)
- An Item needs to have some kind of slots for things like stickers or attachments, which are also items itself.

I need a starting point on how to create this system, as I still need some info about working with classes.

Let's say I created an item class and my first item named "Stick". I have it's instance and want to add this item to a droplist for lootcrates. How do I "pass" it? My basic idea would be to create a copy of it's instance but then I would lose the ability to change it's values afterwards without editing the original instance and the copy itself. This also refers to the inventory itself, when I save a copy of a customized item instance, how do I keep them "linked"?

Comment: So you need a database like sqlite.
You may find better help in the unity forum:
https://forum.unity.com/threads/unity-3d-android-sqlite-examples.114660/

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This probably won't answer everything you asked, but I will try to give you a starting point. You will want to create a base class or interface for all of your inventory items which will contain the properties that all items share (like an ID):

```cs
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

More specific types of items will then inherit from the `Item` class, like perhaps a weapon.

> I want a way to easily manage and modify items and their values, even if they are customized (e.g. when an Item does 20 base dmg and it was modified by the player to do +10 dmg, when I change the base dmg to 30, the players item should do 40 dmg in total)

Your weapon class might have a base damage value, a damage modifier value, and a calculated total damage value based on the previous two:

```cs
public class Weapon : Item
{
    public int BaseDamage { get; set; }
    public int DamageModifier { get; set; }
    public int TotalDamage => BaseDamage + DamageModifier;
}
```

> An Item needs to have some kind of slots for things like stickers or attachments, which are also items itself.

You could create an interface here (or even move this into your base class - I don't know enough about the system you're designing to make that call) which will contain a collection of `Item` objects for this purpose:

```cs
public interface IAttachmentContainer
{
    IEnumerable<Item> Attachments { get; set }
}
```

Then implement this interface on any item that can have attachments.
As for persistence, you will want to look into some type of database system (like Traendy mentioned in the comments).

---

I hope this is enough to get you started. Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: One thing where I could still need some input is the way of storing items in the inventory, so I have my Item created and want to "give" it to the player - How do I store it? I can's save it's ID, as items can be customized, so how exactly do I "pass" a copy of the item to the inventory? And then, how do I access it later, how do I save equipped items without duplicating them? My first basic idea would be an inventory instance which is used to directly access the items with a get function anywhere in the project.

Comment: That works - you could write a class for an inventory that wraps a collection of items. Maybe you could keep an instance of that class inside your player object. For saving the state of the inventory, it might be simpler to use serialization of some kind. You can serialize your inventory instance, then write that to a file.